# How to do with camera plugin cordova 3.4 with two option (CAMERA and SAVEDPHOTOALBUM)

Tags: cordova, camera

Now i develop mobile app cordova 3.4 i know to use camera plugin already. 
but i can use (Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM or Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA ) just only option. I want both. I don't know how to do with mobile behavior can select camera or select to gallery. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the JQuery part:

```
/**
 * Take picture with camera
 */
function takePicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(uri) {
            var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
            img.style.visibility = "visible";
            img.style.display = "block";
            img.src = uri;
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
        },
        { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
};

/**
 * Select picture from library
 */
function selectPicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(uri) {
            var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
            img.style.visibility = "visible";
            img.style.display = "block";
            img.src = uri;
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
        },
        { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
};
```

and here is the html part

```
    <div>
    <input type="button" onclick="takePicture();" value="Take Picture" /><br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="selectPicture();" value="Select Picture from Library" /><br/>
</div>
```

i hope you found your solution 
Thanks